# Understanding the Page events

Tags: nativescript

I have been trying to understand the differences between the Page events in Nativescript, the events I am trying to look into are `loaded`, `navigatingTo` and `navigatedTo`. What I have seen, the 3 of them will be fired everytime you navigate to the Page. What I do not understand is in which order they are executed. I know that `navigatingTo` fires first than `navigatedTo`, that makes sense, but what about `loaded`?

Is `loaded` being fired every time you navigate to the page or just for the first time you navigate to the page?

Is there any event that only executes the first time you navigate to the page? If the app is closed or went to the background and then resumed, it will fire again, of course.

Thanks!!!

Comment: http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=191

Comment: You could also review this article: http://pointdeveloper.com/nativescript-page-navigation-events/

Comment: Excellent articles, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 21):

Supose you are in "Old page" and navigate to "New page", the sequence of events is:

1. Old page triggers its *navigatingFrom*
2. New page triggers its *navigatingTo*
3. Old page triggers its *unloaded*
4. Old page triggers its *navigatedFrom*
5. New page triggers its *loaded*
6. New page triggers its *navigatedTo*

When the app is open, there is no "Old page", so the sequence is:

1. New page triggers its *navigatingTo*
2. New page triggers its *loaded*
3. New page triggers its *navigatedTo*

If app is closed, the app only triggers its *unloaded* event (you put it in background to close it, or power off the device...)

If you run the app in background, the page triggers its *unload* event, and when you resume the app, the page triggers its *loaded* event.

This is my experience, it may not agree with 'reality'

**(Updated: See also: [{N} v7 Page Events](https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/page#page-events))**

Comment: This framework is so amazing, you have to find out these things from stackoverflow, because every other page for {N} says "Uh.. oh... We could not find this page..."